# Grails GORM collection

Tags: grails, collections, grails-orm

Lets say I have to Grails domain classes: Car and Person.

```
class Car {
    String model
    ...
    Person driver
}

class Person {
    String firstName
    String lastName
}
```

I have a set of persons:

```
Set < Person >
```

How can I get a list of all Car instances that have drivers that are in that set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm assuming you have a set of person objects like so:

```
def people = [person1, person2, person3]
```

and you want to retrieve all cars that have one of the 3 drivers:

```
def cars = Car.findAllByDriverInList(people)
```

As long as the objects in the people list are instances of the Person domain you should be good to go.

Comment: Great. I've missed InList. Cool. Can you also show me how to do this with criteria? Thanks.